# unexpected token ',' api call ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

Im getting an unexpected token error in the console when making an call to the Open Weather API.

```
function ajaxCall() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=94040,us);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send();
    var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    console.log(response);
}
```

The error unexpected token is the comma between the zip code and the country.

Comment: i guess should be a `+`

Comment: The URL is missing some quotes -> `"api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=94040,us"`

Comment: This isn't a relative URL. It needs to start with a scheme (like `http://`)

Comment: You're setting a request header claiming you are POSTing JSON, but you have no argument to `send()` so you aren't POSTing anything at all.

Comment: Ahhh ok. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing quotes on your URL. Change:

```
xhttp.open("POST", api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=94040,us);
```

to:

```
xhttp.open("POST", "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=94040,us");
```